# Can't access attribute set on g object in request

Tags: python, flask

I want to use `g` to store an instance of my `DataIO` class.  Then in views I can use `g.data_service` to get the instance.

`app/__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask, g
from data_io import DataIO
myapp = Flask(__name__)

import app.views

with myapp.app_context():
    g.data_service = DataIO()  # DataIO() is my data access class
```

`app/views.py`:

```
from app import myapp
from flask import render_template, request, g

@myapp.route('/panel', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def get_data_by_query():
    ds = getattr(g, 'data_service', None)  # ds is None
    full_list = ds.get_case_list()
```

When I go to "/panel", it raises an exception:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_case_list'
```

The debugger shows that `ds` is `None` rather than an instance of `DataIO`. Why do I get `None` even though I defined it on `g`? How should I add it to `g` correctly so that views can get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `g` namespace is only persistent for a *single* app context.  So as soon as the `with` block closes, the context is gone and so it is not available in the next context when the request comes in.

Perhaps you are looking for [`before_request`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#flask.Flask.before_request), which registers functions to run before each request.

```
from flask import g

@app.before_request
def connect_data():
    # an instance is created before every request
    g.data_service = DataIO()
```

Or perhaps you want an extension, where there is some amount of persistent state per app.

```
from flask import current_app

class DataIOExtension(object):
    def __init__(self, app=None):
        self._app_cache = {}

        if app is not None:
            self.init_app(app)

    def init_app(self, app):
        # an instance is created once per app
        self._app_cache[app] = DataIO()

    @property
    def client(self):
        return self._app_cache[current_app._get_current_object()]

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.client, name)

data_service = DataIOExtension()
data_service.init_app(app)

@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    full_list = data_service.get_case_list()
```

I don't really know the behavior of your `DataIO` class, so this is just an example.  See the [Flask docs on extension development](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/extensiondev/), or check out existing extensions, for more information.